# Ansible: How can I set log file name dynamically?

Tags: ansible

I'm currently developing an Ansible script to build and deploy a Java project.

So, I can set the `log_path` like below

```ini
log_path=/var/log/ansible.log
```

But, it is hard to look up build history.

Is it possible to append datetime to log file name?

For example,

```bash
ansible.20150326145515.log
```

Answer (score 15):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to generate the date on the fly like that but one option you have is to use a [lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups) which can shell out to date.  Example:

```
log_path="/var/log/ansible.{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}.log"
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you? For me, running 2.3.2.0, the quotes are escaped by the interpreter, resulting in the `log_path` being invalid; never even attempting to execute the lookup.

Comment: Sorry, it creates files named `ansible-log.{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}.log` instead of doing something useful. Putting quotes around the whole path makes ansible append `pwd` to it.

Comment: This doesnt work for me:ansible 2.7.8
  config file = /root/scripts/ansible/affinities/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Comment: How does this have 17 upvotes? It does not work. Just tried it on Ansible 2.9.7.

Comment: @EM0 have you find any solution?

Comment: According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html, this syntax only works with Ansible >= 3.5.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an option using `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH` environment variable thanks to Bash shell alias:

```
alias ansible="ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=ansible-\`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S\`.log ansible"
```

Feel free to use an absolute path if you prefer.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about the env vars. This seems to be the way to set the log path when running from a *sh script using `export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=...`.

Answer (score 5):

I found it.

just add task to copy(or mv command) log locally

```
- name: Copy ansible.log
  connection: local
  command: mv ./logs/ansible.log ./logs/ansible.{{ lookup('pipe', 'date %Y%M%d%H%M%S') }}.log
  run_once: true
```

thanks to @jarv

Comment: Be careful that your date format is missing the `+` sign from @jarv's answer.

Comment: I tested that this works. I started by deleting the existing log; making a playbook to: execute a debug task to begin writing to the log, execute the command task to move/rename the log, execute another task to see if Ansible still correctly writes to the log. The result is a success – the log was created by ansible, written to, renamed, and written to again after moving/renaming.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
- shell: date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
  register: timestamp

- debug: msg="foo.{{timestamp.stdout}}.log"
```

Output:

```
TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [blabla.example.com]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [blabla.example.com] => {
    "msg": "foo.20160922233847.log"
}
```

Comment: I think you were down voted because he needs to change the log file dynamically – which involves modifying the log_path – not just use the debug module to show that you can do the `date` command with Ansible.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem while trying to set dynamic log paths for various playbooks.

A simple solution seems to be to pass the log filename dynamically to the ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH environment variable. Checkout -> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

In this particular case just export the environment variable when running the intended playbook on your terminal:

```
export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=ansible.`date +%s`.log; ansible-playbook test.yml
```

Else if the intended filename cannot be generated by the terminal, you can always use a runner playbook which runs the intended playbook from the within:

```
    ---
- hosts:
    - localhost
  gather_facts: false
  ignore_errors: yes
  tasks:
    - name: set dynamic variables
      set_fact:
        task_name: dynamic_log_test
        log_dir: /path/to/log_directory/
    - name: Change the working directory and run the ansible-playbook as shell command
      shell: "export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH={{ log_dir }}log_{{ task_name|lower }}.txt; ansible-playbook test.yml"
      register: shell_result
```

This should log the result of test.yml to /path/to/log_directory/log_dynamic_log_test.txt

Hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 1):

According to the nice folks at the #ansible freenode IRC, this can be accomplished with a [custom callback plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-callback-plugins).

I haven't done it yet because I can't install the Ansible Python library on this machine. Specifically, Windows 7 can't have directory names > 260 chars in length, and `pip` tries to make [lengthy](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3055) temporary paths. But if someone gets around to it, please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Small improvement on @ickhyun-kwon answer:

```
- name: "common/_ansible_log_path.yml: rename ansible.log"
  connection: local
  shell: |
    mkdir -vp {{ inventory_dir }}/logs/{{ svn_deploy.release }}/ ;
    mv    -vf {{ inventory_dir }}/logs/ansible.log {{ inventory_dir }}/logs/{{ svn_deploy.release }}/ansible.{{ svn_deploy.release }}.{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M') }}.log      args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    chdir: "{{ inventory_dir }}"
  run_once: True
  ignore_errors: True
```

This has separate log directories per svn release, ensures the log directory actually exists before the mv command.

Ansible interprets `./` as the current playbook directory, which may or may not be the root of your ansible repository, whereas mine live in `./playbooks/$project/$role.yml`. For me `{{ inventory_dir }}/logs/` happens to correspond to the `~/ansible/log/` directory, though alternative layout configurations do not guarantee this.

I am unsure the correct way to formally extract the absolute ansible.cfg::log_path variable

Also the date command for month is `+%m` and not `%M` which is Minute