# Get the pid of a running playbook for use within the playbook

Tags: linux, ansible, pid

When we run a playbook, with verbose output enabled, in the ansible logs we can see something like this:

`2016-02-03 12:51:58,235 p=4105 u=root |  PLAY RECAP`

I guess that the `p=4105` is the pid of the playbook when it ran.

Is there a way to get this pid inside the playbook during its runtime (as a variable for example)?

Comment: I don't think that's available directly, but what are you trying to do with the PID? I think @larsks has a good answer if you really need it

Comment: @DaveSnigier What I am trying to achieve is relevant to [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135954/how-to-log-in-a-separate-file-per-playbook-in-ansible) . I am trying to extract the entries related to a specific playbook from the ansible log, in order to create a separate log (I guess that's one way of doing it).

Comment: IF someone find the answer let this question also answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436621/combine-ps-eaf-with-awk-command-output

Answer (score 4):

You can define the PID for localhost using the `set_fact` module with a `lookup` filter.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        pid: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'echo $PPID') }}"
```

And later on you can reference the `PID` via the `hostvars` dictionary.

```
- hosts: remote
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars.localhost.pid
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a little like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but one option may be to spawn a shell with the `shell` command and then ask for the parent PID:

```
- name: get pid of playbook
  shell: |
    echo "$PPID"
  register: playbook_pid
```

This will give you the PID of the `python` process that is executing the playbook.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly, I get back a pid that is not relevant with the pid in the logs. Btw, that may be indeed a XY problem. Please check my comment above of why I want to do something like this. Maybe you can help in my other question here in SO.

Comment: You'd want to ensure this runs on the local system, not the target host.  Either add `delegate_to: localhost`, or rewrite it using `local_action:`.  The PPID you're getting with this snippet is from the target host, not the localhost.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for, but is only applicable to Linux:

```
- name: Get the pid of this playbook
  shell: pstree -spal $PPID | grep ansible-playbook | awk '{print $1;exit}' | awk -F, '{print $2}'
  register: ansible_pid

- name: Set the ansible playbook pid variable
  set_fact:
    ansible_playbook_pid: "{{ ansible_pid.stdout|int }}"
```

Comment: Does the value of this process ID keep changing from task to task ? I tried this method but it keeps changing in between tasks

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using the pid in different plays, just add it to the `setup` module.

```
setup_result['ansible_facts']['ansible_pid'] = os.getpid()
```

and it will always be available.

```
    "ansible_os_family": "Debian",
    "ansible_pid": 27930,
    "ansible_pkg_mgr": "apt",
```

Comment: The setup module is executed for every host. If you run the code on 200 hosts, it calls 200 times `getpid` although the `PID` of the Ansible host is always the same. This means, it is the wrong place to do this in the setup module.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the `pids` module new with v2.8. which delivers all pids for a specific process name to you.

Simple example to get Pids of Ansible Playbooks on host machines:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: "get pids! and no, 'ansible-playboo' is no typo"
      pids:
        name: ansible-playboo
      register: pids_of_python

    - name: "Print pids"
      debug:
        msg: "PIDs: {{ pids_of_python.pids|join(',') }}"
```

Downside: you'll have to install `psutil`

Please refer to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pids_module.html

Comment: looking for ansible 2.7.9 or below, thanks for responding

Comment: Also this will print all the pid of ansible-playbooks which is undesired , here I need to grab the pid of the current playbook from the same playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent PID

```yaml
  pid: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ps -o ppid= -p $PPID') }}"
```